# updating data with variables in SQLite python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a piece of code in python that allows the user to enter their username, password and date of birth and then allows them to change this information. This is what I have so far.

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
cursor=conn.cursor()

def createTable():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userInfo(username TEXT, password TEXT, dateOfBirth TEXT)")

def enterData():
    inputUser=input("Enter your username")
    inputPass=input("Enter your password")
    inputDoB=input("Enter your date of birth")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO userInfo (username, password, dateOfBirth) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
          (inputUser, inputPass, inputDoB))
    conn.commit()


def modifyData():
    update=input("would you like to change your username")
    if update=="yes":
        newUsername=input("Update your username")
        cursor.execute("UPDATE userInfo SET username='?' WHERE username='?'",(newUsername, user))
        conn.commit

createTable()
enterData()
modifyData()
```

It allows me to enter the data but I don't know the specific syntax for updating the data value to a variable. When I try and run this code, this error appears:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 7 supplied.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the full traceback - what line is it occurring at? Where is `user` coming from in `modifyData`... also you don't need the `'`s around the `?`s in the update statement...

Comment: This code would give a NameError because you have not defined `user`.

Comment: Interestingly you quote the `?` placeholders in `UPDATE` but not in `INSERT`.

Comment: Not just *don't need* to quote the `?`s, but *must not*. When you quote them you're telling the database to replace your data with a literal string containing only `?`, rather than to look for a piece of data passed out-of-band.

Answer (score 1):

When I've copied it and run the first error that occurred said that variable `user` is not defined. Therefore you need to either send it to function `modifyData` from `enterData` or ask the user for it.

Then I've got the error you've mentioned. Just remove the single quotes around `?`

Code:

```
def modify_data():
    update = input('Would you like to change your username[y/N]: ')
    if update.lower() == 'y':
        old_username = input('Old username: ')
        new_username = input('Update your username: ')
        cursor.execute('UPDATE userInfo SET username=? WHERE username=?', (new_username, old_username))
    conn.commit()
```

By the way, I've found [this tool](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) that can help you visualize it. (It's free and open source)

Comment: `cursor.execute` needs a comma.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want `raw_input`, not `input`.

`raw_input` reads data from standard input and returns it. `input()` is equivelant to `eval(raw_input())`: i.e., it evaluates the input as Python code.

I'm not 100% sure if this is your root problem though, if you've already been using quotes around your input? Or maybe you're not -- can you provide all the input and output from a run of this program?

Comment: If this were the OP's immediate issue they'd have a completely different error. (That it's *not* their immediate issue implies that they're on Python 3, where `input()` behaves identically to Python 2's `raw_input()`).

Comment: It's hard to say what the immediate issue would be without knowing what the input is, but yes, given that's how python 3 behaves that's the more likely explanation.